# Need to get dates between last April and next March in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, select, mariadb, between

Exclusively in MySQL, I need to get the date for `last April` and `next March`.

This is easy in PHP as the DateTime functions literally allow you to enter `last April` and it will give you a date.

I want to select records where their date is between 01-04-2021 and then 31-03-2022 – BUT, when the 1st of April 2022 comes around, I need it to automatically change to 01-04-2022 and 31-03-2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be

```
SELECT  .....
WHERE somedate BETWEEN 
    CONCAT(IF(MONTH( CURDATE() ) < 4, YEAR( CURDATE() ) - 1, YEAR( CURDATE() )), '-04-01') 
    AND
    CONCAT(IF(MONTH( CURDATE() ) < 4, YEAR( CURDATE() ), YEAR( CURDATE() )+1), '-03-31');
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you!!